# What does return -1 mean in Java? If it inches is <0, do we still proceed to calculate inches/12 and inches%12?

Tags: java, overloading, return-value

If it inches is <0, do we still proceed to calculate  inches/12 and inches%12?

```
public static double calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(double inches) {
if(inches<0) {
return -1;
 
}
double feet=(int)inches /12;
double remainingInches=(int)inches % 12;
System.out.println(inches + "inches is equal to " + feet + "fee and " + remainingInches + " remaining inches");
return calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(feet, remainingInches);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "return" stop the execution of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332414/does-return-stop-the-execution-of-a-method)

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger.

Answer (score 3):

`return -1;` doesn't mean anything, beyond the fact you are saying the result of the method invocation is -1, presumably to somehow indicate that the input was invalid.

This isn't a very good idea, though, because -1 is a valid double, so you can accidentally forget to check the result and continue using this "invalid" result.

It would be better to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if you don't want to accept negative values.

Comment: Or, even better, accept the input and return a negative conversion result.

Comment: @jsheeran "even better" maybe, maybe not. Depends what you're trying to do. It's definitely an option.